# Finding the Probability of a Sequence of Numbers in Materials Testing

Tags: probability, statistics

There are $n$ numbers on a wheel. For this example, let's say $n = 20$. You are going to spin $x$ times. For this example, let's say $x = 7$. The chances of spinning the same number all 7 times is $\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^x$ or 1 in 1,280,000,000 for this example. For materials testing, the smaller the probability, the more likely someone cheated. What formula can I use to find the probability of having the same number occur 4 times and a different number occur 3 times? Or the odds that 7 different numbers will occur? Or the odds that 3 numbers are the same, 2 numbers are the same, 2 more numbers are the same? etc. The numbers do not have to be in order or consecutive and all 20 numbers can occur each spin.

My thought is this is a complex equation that can simply be solved.

Also, what are the odds that all 7 numbers are in the bottom half, bottom quarter, middle quarter, etc. of the numbers?

Please note: This sounds similar to roulette, but I promise this isn't roulette. I just know roulette terminology more than probability. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Actually, if you have not picked the number first, you probability is $\frac{1}{n}^{n-1}$ since your first number is "free;" just setting the requirement for the next $n-1$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. However, is there a formula to correlate n and x? You are correct, the first number is free. Let's assume n > x.

Comment: When I said "What formula can I use to find the probability of having the same number occur 4 times and a different number occur 3 times?" to clarify, the 4 times and 3 times occurred at the same 7 "x" spins. The probability of that happen would be less than 4 times being the same number and the other 3 numbers being different (in the 7 spins). I need to be able to numerically prove that this is true, which is why I am asking the questions. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by correlate $n$ and $x$. If the $n$ options are all uniformly randomly distributed, then picking any one of them has probability $\frac{1}{n}$. If each selection is independent, then the probabilities for seeing the same event $x$ times is just the probability of that event multiplied by itself $x$ times, or $p^x$. If the choices are *not* independent, it is a much tougher question, and may require probability trees if it cannot be formulated in terms of a more basic distribution. It does depends on what your belief about the initial distribution is.

Comment: @Avraham By correlating n and x, I mean if you have n=6 numbers and x = 2 spins, then (1/6)^2 or (1/n)^x. In my materials testing, x will always be 7 for a test and we're talking about a test that produces random numbers. Half the numbers are actually negative numbers and the other half are even. So for a test, 4 (we'll call it x1) of the numbers are "b" and the other 3 numbers (we'll call it x2) are "c" how do I calculate the probability of that happening (b and c can be any of the "n" numbers). Would it be as simple (1/n)^4 + (1/n)^3?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that each number has the same probability of occurring as any other number, and that the result of one "spin" is independent of any other spin, I believe you are looking at a [multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution).

In your case, you have 20 categories and will spin 7 times. So the probability of any one single predetermined  number 4 times and any other single predetermined number 3 times (where order is NOT important) should be:
$$
\frac{7!}{4!3!}\left(\frac{1}{20}\right)^4\left(\frac{1}{20}\right)^3\\
=\frac{35}{1280000000}
$$

In your case, I believe your numbers are not predetermined, so I believe we can look at this as 3 predetermined draws from the first "free" number and 2 predetermined draws from the second number. In which case, we would have the total number of possible acceptable draws being:

$$
\underbrace{{20 \choose 1}\cdot\frac{1}{20}}_{\text{First choice}}\overbrace{\cdot{1 \choose 1}\cdot\frac{1}{20^3}}^{\text{Next three copies}}\underbrace{{19 \choose 1}\cdot\frac{1}{20}}_{\text{The "next" number}}\overbrace{\cdot{1 \choose 1}\cdot\frac{1}{20^2}}^{\text{Next two copies}}\underbrace{\cdot\frac{7!}{4!3!}}_{\text{Ways to distribute choices}}\\
=\frac{20\cdot 19\cdot35}{1280000000}
$$

In the first case, consider that since the numbers are fixed, the ${20 \choose 1}$ and ${19 \choose 1}$ both become ${1 \choose 1}$. The last term is the number of ways that four copies of one object and three copies of another can be distributed in 7 slots, if each of the copies is indistinguishable from each other.

For the odds seven different numbers occur, well, you get 1 free, then you have 19 choices for the second, 18 choices for the third, etc.

For the odds of all seven in the bottom half, well, how many ways are there to pick numbers from only the bottom half, and how many ways total. Probability is really all about counting. Assuming the 10 and 20 split, there are $10^7$ ways to pick the first ten numbers and $20^7$ ways to pick all numbers so $\frac{10^7}{20^7}$ should be your answer. Answers for different subset sizes can be found similarly.

### Update (based on discussion in comments below)

A more intuitive way to look at this would be as follows. The numerator is the number of ways to have distinguishable sets of 4 and 3 items from the pool of 20. So, from the 20 items we first pick the 2 that will be seen. From those 2, we then pick which will be the "four". From 4 we pick 4. From the remaining 1 we pick one, and then from the 3 items we pick all three. This is the number of combinations of 4 & 3. However, order is important in the question, so we lastly have to consider the number of distinct permutations that a set of 4 and 3 items can show in 7 slots. The denominator is simply the total possible number of observations. Symbolically (the items in gray equate to 1 and are there just to follow the textual example more closely):
$$\Large
\frac{{20 \choose 2}{2 \choose 1}\color{gray}{{4 \choose 4}{1 \choose 1}{3 \choose 3}}\frac{7!}{4!3!}}{20^7}
$$ Which is
$$\frac{20\times 19\times 35}{1280000000}
$$ As before. This way of thinking about it is probably more intuitive. So for the question in the comments we would approach it this way: From the 20, choose the 6 items which will be seen. From these 6, pick the one that will be seen twice. Technically, we would then select the 2 items and put them in two slots and the the remaining 5 singletons and put them one each into the open slots, but both of those are equal to 1 as ${n \choose n} = 1$. That handles the combinations. For the permutations, there are $\frac{7!}{2!}$ possible unique orderings in 7 slots of 5 distinct items and a pair. The denominator remains $20^7$ or the universe of all possible length 7 strings from 20 items. This becomes:
$$
\frac{{20 \choose 6}{6 \choose 1}\frac{7!}{2!}}{20^7}\\
\frac{38760\times 6 \times 2520}{1280000000} \approx 45.78\%
$$
As in the comments below; another example of the beauty of combinatorics. If you approach the problem correctly (or at least consistently), you have to get the same answer--since it is all about counting real items.

Comment: I'm trying to understand this. Why are there 3 and 2 copies and not 4 and 3? Also, with 7 spins when "n" greater than 7, then there could be 7 unique numbers. There are 15 (I believe) possibilities for the unique numbers to occur. That is for example, 7 of 1 unique number or 6 of 1 unique number and 1 of another unique number or 5 of 1 unique number, 1 of another unique number, and 1 of another unique number, etc. How would you incorporate those into the 2nd equation? Also, the "way to distribute" would be 7!/(x!y!z!a!b!c!d!), where x+y+z+a+b+c+d=7 correct?

Comment: Next three COPIES of the First choice, for a total of 4. Next two COPIES of the second choice, for a total of 3.I don't understand your second sentence. If there are 7 copies of one number, it isn't unique. If order doesn't matter, and there are $n$ numbers from which you want to pick $k$ without replacement (so they are unique), then the answer is ${n \choose k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. When I do your equation I'm off by 1/20. I think it is because of the first choice where I get 1 or 20/20. The 2nd sentence: What I'm trying to do is develop a formula in Excel to auto-calc the probability for any scenario. There are ultimately 15 different scenarios with potentially up to 7 unique numbers (in the 7 spins).

Comment: I am still trying to figure out your formula and I am getting probabilities of over 1. For example, 7 unique numbers with "n" numbers. I believe it has to do with the "ways to distribute" section of your equation. Any help would be great!

Comment: If you have $n$ items (billiard balls for example) which are broken into $x_1, x_2,\ldots,x_k$ indistinguishable colors, then the total unique permutations are $\frac{n!}{x_1!\cdot x_2!\cdot\ldots\cdot x_k!}$. The numerator is the number of permutations if all the balls were distinct, and the denominator comprises the permutations of the indistinct terms (red balls, green balls), each of which is indistinguishable from the other. Hope that helps.

Comment: I understand that part. So lets try this scenario: I have 20 unique numbers, I am drawing 7 times, and I draw 7 unique numbers. So 7!/(1!x1!x1!x1!x1!x1!x1!) = 5040. So I would have [(20 1)x(1/20)]x[(19 0)x(1/20)]x...[(14 0)x(1/20)]x5040. If I did (20 1) correctly, then this should = 20 and (19 0) = 19, etc. I would ultimately get a probability of 0.305235 x 5040 = 1538.3844 > 1. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: I believe the issue with your example is that there are no indistinguishable elements; there are no "copies" since we didn't specify which number would be first or second, so that is already taken care of. Only when there are "copies" within the numbers are we concerned, as we don't care which two **of type X** was picked first. So the probability is just $20\times 19\times 18\times 17\times 16\times 15\times 14\times 20^{-7}$. As each number is a set of one, the last term is not appropriate, as it cannot swap with another of its type.

Comment: So when would the "ways to distribute" come into play? If I have my scenario, but I am drawing 7 times, and I draw 1 unique number twice and the other 5 drawings are unique numbers. Without the "ways to distribute" I get 0.0218, which I believe it too low. Hopefully I am not getting to annoying.

Comment: I hope someone corrects me if I am wrong, but I would say that situation should be approached as such: from 20 pick the 5 uniques, from the remaining 15, pick 1, and then adjust for identical orderings. In other words:$${20 \choose 5}\times 20^{-5}\times {15 \choose 1}\times 20^{-2}\times \frac{7!}{2!} \approx 45.75\%$$

Comment: The above should be $45.78\%$; transcription error (third digit is 5) sorry.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the first question, first consider the probability of this event happening:
$$1,1,1,1,1,2,2$$
Where $1$ and $2$ can be replaced with any integer $[0,n]$ so long as they are different. The first choice is free, however every $1$ after it has a $\frac{1}{n}$ chance of agreeing. The odds of the first $2$ being a number that is not $1$ is simply $\frac{n-1}{n}$, and the odds of every number after it also being $2$ is again $\frac{1}{n}$ for every number. However, it is important to note that permutations such as
$$2,1,2,1,1,1,1\ \ \text{and}\ \ 1,1,1,2,1,2,1$$
increase the chances of the desired event happening. In order to account for those we have to consider every permutation of $1,1,1,1,1,2,2$ without repeats, which would simply be $\frac{7!}{5!2!}$. Therefore, if we take our set of $n$ items, the odds of getting one element of the set $k_1$ times, another element of the set $k_2$ times, all the way to $k_j$ would be shown by:

(The sum of $k_1, k_2, \cdots, k_j$ = $x$)
$$ P = \Big[x!\prod_{i=1}^j \frac{1}{k_i!}\Big] \cdot \Big[\Big(\frac{1}{n}\Big)^{x-j}\Big] \cdot \Big[\prod_{i=0}^j \frac{n-i}{n}\Big]$$
The first product takes care of the fact that order does not matter, the second product checks the odds of the same number being hit again, and the third product takes care of the fact that $1,1,1,1,1$ does not count as getting 2 1's and 3 1's, but simply 5 1's.

As for the second question:
$$P_2 = P \cdot \Big( \frac{1}{a} \Big)^j$$
where $a$ is how you are partitioning the set. (One half $\Rightarrow a=2$, One third $\Rightarrow a=3$, etc)

Note: If you care for the derivation of $\frac{7!}{5!2!}$, it is simply a generalization of the familiar $C_n^k$ to multiple subsets instead of just 2 . The first product in my solution answers the question "How many ways can you partition a set into $j$ subsets of sizes $k_1,k_2,\cdots,k_j$". The proof if found in Theorem 1.4 of [http://www.amazon.com/Probability-Theory-Concise-Course-Mathematics-ebook/dp/B00DP7ULZY/ref=tmm_kin_title_0?_encoding=UTF8&sr=&qid=](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DP7ULZY) (Click the picture to see the first chapter of the book).

Comment: One of the beautiful properties of combinatorics is that since it has to be counting items, if you count properly, you must get to the right answer regardless of *how* you count. If you substitute the 7, 4, 3, and 20 in the right places in Nicholas's general formula, you get the specific one in my answer (with the over and under braces). The first term is the $\frac{7!}{4!3!}$, the second term is simply $\frac{1}{20^5}$ which are the "copy probabilities" in my answer, and the last term is $\frac{20\cdot19}{20^2}$ which are the "first choice" and "next choice" in the answer above.